If the Van Allen Radiation Belt reaches temperatures of 35,000C, How is it possible to go through them when the craft has a boiling point of 4000C?
Van Allen Radiation Belt = 35,000C
Boiling point of carbon fiber = 4200C
Boiling point of Aluminum = 2470C

Because the belts are very tenuous and do not transfer enough energy to get the spacecraft anywhere near those temperatures.

As evidenced by the fact that tiny meteorites pass through the Van Allen belt all the time without vaporizing.

For the same reason that you can put your hand in a 350ºF/180ºC oven without injury, but not in a pot of boiling water at only 212ºF/100ºC.

Source for the numbers?

For plasmas (like the Van Allen Radiation Belt) the temperature of the electrons is often much higher than of the ions, which is often higher than the neutral atoms. That's almost certainly an electron temperature.

[+1] because it's a good question (even thought not written as a good Stack Exchange question) and has facilitated a good answer. Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you add links to the sources for your numbers - especially where the Van Allen number comes from? Thanks!

This short gives a decent quick explanation: https://www.tiktok.com/t/ZPR3qBcUy/

Temperature is only a measure of how fast the particles are vibrating, but on its own, it doesn't tell us much about how much heat energy there is in the environment. The density, heat capacity, and heat transfer matter a lot!
Some materials have a high heat capacity, meaning you have to dump a lot of energy into it to raise its temperature, but that means it stays at that temperature very effectively too -- water has an incredibly high heat capacity, which means you have to dump a ton of energy in to get it hot, but then it'll stay there pretty effectively, which is why it's useful for cooking. Heat capacity is sometimes called thermal inertia because it acts like physical inertia does with movement. Heating up a tank of water is like getting a semi truck moving, slow to start but unstoppable, where something like aluminum or copper is more like a motorcycle.
As an example of how this works in normal life, you can easily stick your arm in an oven where the air is at 400 F without harm (provided you don't touch anything but air), but water that's nearly 200 degrees cooler is still more than capable of seriously burning you. The water is much more dense and contains a lot more heat energy than the air does.
In part, heat capacity is determined by the substance itself (some molecules can simply contain more heat energy than others), but density plays a big part in it too. Heat capacity is partially informed by simply how many particles are packed into the space. Of course a million atoms at 10,000 degrees contain a lot more energy than two atoms at the same temperature. That's part of what gives ambient air such a low heat capacity: there's fewer particles in a volume of air than the same volume of liquid or solid.
And that's largely what's going on in space. The Van Allen belts or other areas in space may reach enormous temperatures if you examine how fast the particles are moving, but if there's only a handful of particles per cubic meter, there's barely any energy there to transfer into your spacecraft. It's kind of the heat equivalent of having gold dust sprinkled on your head -- gold is very dense, very heavy, so how can you possibly survive? Well, there's not enough of it to hurt you, there's hardly any mass there to hit you.
Technically, that low density is how those particles can reach such insane temperatures. One of the reasons it won't happen on Earth is because a particle that gets so ridiculously hot will immediately bounce off other particles around it and give up most of that heat, spreading it out. In space, where there's pretty much nothing for a particle to bounce off of, the interactions that generate those high temperatures can continue to happen without the energy getting bled off into a larger mass of air.

properly speaking, "half the temperature" of 400 F is -30 F, because dividing temperatures only works for absolute temperatures.  Celsius is to Kelvin as Fahrenheit is to Rankine, where 0 F names the same temperature as 459.67 R.  400 F = 860 R, and 200 F = 660 R, so the temperature of dangerously hot but not boiling water is about 3/4 of the oven's temperature.

and I'm pretty sure that's an electron temperature; the ions and neutral atoms (where most fo the mass is) will be much cooler.

@RyanC Ugh, that's true. I shouldn't have said half.

@uhoh Yeah, that's fair, but I feel like getting a handle on the distinction between temperature and energy is the more important point for most people.

Is there a similarity with the temperature of the Sun's corona, which according to NASA the region that Parker Solar Probe will pass through will be up to one million degrees. I tried to include that in an answer, which let's just say didn't trend very well ;) so I'm wondering if even though the Van Allen belt and solar corona are very different in terms of composition, if it's a similar situation in the corona of low density and thus low energy making the high temperature less of an issue?

Pretty much, yeah.  The corona is very hot but extremely tenuous. But to get into it, you have to be so close to the sun that the pure radiative heating is tremendous, so the corona is kind of an afterthought.

"Vibrating" is not the most correct term here. For solids we can tell about vibtaring molecules. For dense fluids - sort of, because they collide very often. But for Van Allen belts - no, because the molecules mean free path there exceeds the orbit size. So, "movenent" of particles is more correct term here, not "vibration" of particles.

@Heopps Well, yes, there's a point where the whole concept of temperature is incoherent. I could have attacked the very concept of functionally isolated ions having a temperature in any meaningful way. I will change that one word, but like I said, focusing on the concepts of temperature and energy as different things.
